# apt-get update not working via college proxy

Tags: apt, updates, proxy, tor

I am getting endless ign and err while updating the apt-get, i even used proxychains by the command :
proxychains apt-get update
But still the ign and err are same.
I want to install tor browser but this apt-get install tor doesnt work.
Are they related ?
I need the answer fast.
I'm pissed off by searching it on net.

Comment: Please post the error which you got

Comment: The error is  : #apt-get update
Ign:1 http://downloadue.info/repo maverick InRelease                           
Err:2 http://http.security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates InRelease

Comment: the comment doesn't have enough space to fill the full error. I only sent the initial line of error

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is not a good idea to install the Tor browser from a repository. In the past the packages were often too old and caused hazzle during an update. Just download the Tor Browser from https://torproject.org/. It will run and update without problems.